# MVC Ajax callbacks order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, msdn

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the OnComplete callback from an Ajax call in MVC gets executed before OnSuccess or OnFailure, I quote

> OnComplete:   Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call when response data has been instantiated but before the page is updated.
>
> OnFailure:    Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call if the page update fails.
>
> OnSuccess:    Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call after the page is successfully updated.

However, looking at the extension code that maps these callbacks, they are mapped to the *complete*, *success* and *error* callbacks from jQuery.ajax() and [the documentation for that](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says that the *complete* callback is

> A function to be called when the request finishes **(after success and error callbacks are executed)**

A simple test proved that indeed OnComplete gets called after OnSuccess or OnFailure.

Am I missing something or is the MSDN documentation wrong?
I should say that my code doesn't use a target placeholder id but rather executes custom code to update the DOM, does that factor in anything?

I need the OnComplete callback to do what is doing but my main concern is that the documentation, as I understood it, says otherwise.